# How to capture kafka records that don't match the condition of the kafka stream join?

Tags: join, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm doing data enrichment by joining a kstream with a ktable. The kstream contains messages sent by vehicles and the ktable contains vehicle data.
The problem i have is that i want to capture message from the stream that don't have a corresponding join key in the table.
Kafka stream silently skip records that they don't have a join match.
Is there some way to emit those records to a different topic, so they can be processed later?

```
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final KTable<String, VinMappingInfo> vinMappingTable = builder.table(vinInfoTopic, Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), valueSerde));
        KStream<String, VehicleMessage> vehicleStream = builder.stream(sourceTopic);
        vehicleStream.join(vinMappingTable, (vehicleMsg, vinInfo) -> {
            log.info("joining {} with vin info {}", vehicleMsg.getPayload().getId(), vinInfo.data.vin);
            vehicleMsg.setVin(vinInfo.data.vin);
            return vehicleMsg;
        }, Joined.with(null, null, valueSerde))
                .to(destinationTopic);

        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        log.info("The topology of connected processor nodes: \n {}", topology.describe());
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
        streams.cleanUp();
        streams.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left-join:

```java
stream.leftJoin(table,...);
```

This ensures the all records from the input stream are in the output stream. The `ValueJoiner` will be called with `apply(streamValue, null)` for this case.

Comment: Hi Matthias J. Sax, I am trying to get the event which is not processed during KStream to KStream join after window period expired. This is for retry if incase join stream data arrives later point of time.

Comment: That is not easily possible.

Comment: @matthias-j-sax Any work around to identify??? Because, I am using KStream join with window now, there is possible to have delay 1 or 2 or 3 days one stream. I don't want to have such huge window/grace period. Since, my apps will have high data flow ~50 millions events per day. So I would like to identify non join message and process differently. Appreciate your help so solve this.

Comment: You could use an upstream `transformValue` that tracks "stream-time" manually and "branches off" records that would be dropped in the join upfront. "stream-time" is just the max event-timestamp seen so it's easy to compute -- however, you might need a state store to make the tracking fault-tolerant (until KIP-622 lands: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-622%3A+Add+currentSystemTimeMs+and+currentStreamTimeMs+to+ProcessorContext)

Comment: Hi Matthias, could you please elaborate a bit on your proposal. I would especially like to understand how the solution to report unjoined events could work without state stores (now that KIP-622 has been implemented). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of tracking and storing stream-time in a state store, you can just call `context.currentStreamTimeMs()` from the runtime. Thus, your upstream `transformValues` can be stateless.

Comment: I struggle to understand the stateless solution. I thought that in the upstream transformValues we would put all messages into a state store. After a join, we can haven another transformValues that would remove the joined events from that store. In the second transformValues we would also launch a punctuator that would check the content of the state store and remove and forward the unjoined events (e.g. using the stream time) for error handling or reporting. But you seem to imply that there might be a solution without state stores, do not you? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think that you need a upstream state store. You just do the LEFT join, and after the join you check if the result record was enriched or not (something you can do without a state store). A LEFT join does not drop any stream records -- only an INNER join drop non-matching stream records. Thus, every stream input record produces one result record.

Comment: The trouble with the LEFT join is that it always produces a result for a value in the left stream. Thus, I cannot report unjoined records by just looking at the join result as many times I would see <message,null> in the beginning of the time window (i.e. the moment the message in the left stream is produced) just because the right stream does not have a matching message yet. And in that case, there will be no second <message,null> at the end of the time window.  Therefore, we would not know that the message in the left stream has not been joined. Happy to learn if this understanding is wrong

Comment: I think we are talking about two different things :). `always produces a result for a value in the left stream. Thus, I cannot report unjoined records by just looking at the join result` -- I disagree, the `<message,null>` does exactly tell you that the message did not join. Period. Note that a stream-table join has no concept of a window (that you mentioned).

Comment: `just because the right stream does not have a matching message yet.` -> the key here is the "yet", ie, your question is not about detecting that a record did not join, but about "how can I change the join semantics (eg, by adding a window or similar) to "make the record join" (if maybe later,a matching table side records appears). -- I would recommend to start a new question... (or join Confluent community slack or developer forum: easier to discuss there).

Comment: Matthias, you are right - it turns out that I did not read the question carefully. I am rather interested in reporting unjoined messages in a stream/stream join scenario. And now I understand your proposal as it is related to the stream/table join. I will follow your advice and start a new discussion (perhaps in the forum)! Thanks a lot!